# Postgresql compiled from source WAL file compatibility with ubuntu package

Tags: postgresql

Pardon my ignorance.

Is it possible to use the WAL files generated by Postgresql compiled from source (version 8.3.5) by an Ubuntu Postgresql package (8.3.4)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compilation options.

Generally - is it the same architecture (same os, 32/64 bit?), and is "integer datetimes" set to the same value on both postgreses? if yes - it should work.